# How to update my twitter status using php script?

Tags: php, twitter

I want to update my twitter account status(I want to post a new tweet) from my site using php. Is there any help for this? Please help me if any one has done this before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used this http://simpleauthtwitter.heroku.com/ service and curl. Did not have enough time to fully understand oauth, so this service helped a lot. Is it safe? i have no idea, but it did the job. I can post messages to twitter

example:

```
$message = 'your message';
$url = "http://simpleauthtwitter.heroku.com/tweet?api_key=your-simple-auth-api-key&status=".urlencode($message);
$curl_handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```